# Make a responsive text placement in Bootstrap's jumbotron

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a page with a jumbotron header. the page is - http://www.mzungu.co.il/article.php?id=10

The size of the jumbotron is 40vmax:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image:url('images/<?php echo $article_cover ?>');
    background:repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 35vmax;
    background-position:center center;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 4px black;
}
```

the code i have tried so far is:

```
.jumbotron h1,
.jumbotron .h1 {
    position:relative; top 30vmax;
}
```

with many different variations of position (fixed, absolute, etc) and with "margin top". could not find something that would work for both pc and mobile view.

Also, i wanted to create a background just for the text part, like in  [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUZnw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

this maybe can help you out.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_hero_image

and for the background of the text you may do it like this.

```
.h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;

    h1 {
        padding: 6px;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background: rgba(192,192,192,.7);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 1.8;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        transition: all 1s ease-out;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the link helped me out with the location, but i copied the background part and it didnt do anything..